# Whats the right BlobStorageService Configuration format?

Tags: botframework, azure-storage

When creating a Microsoft Bot Framework 4 project - the Startup.cs has the following code which can be uncommented.

```
const string StorageConfigurationId = "<NAME OR ID>";
var blobConfig = botConfig.FindServiceByNameOrId(StorageConfigurationId);
if (!(blobConfig is BlobStorageService blobStorageConfig))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot file does not contain an blob storage with name '{StorageConfigurationId}'.");
}
```

This code handles a way to configure an Azure Storage Account via Json Configuration.

However the project lacks an example on what the config Json looks like for the "is BlobStorageService" to work.

I have done various tries and searched for examples but cannot make it work.

Has anyone got the nailed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using this json...

```
{
  "type": "blob", //Must be 'blob' 
  "name": "<NAME OF CONFIG - MUST BE UNIQUE (CAN BE ID)>",
  "connectionString": "<COPY FROM AZURE DASHBOARD>",
  "container": "<NAME OF CONTAINER IN STORAGE>"
}
```